# is ->Release() called on the destructor of COM objects?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, directx

If I have the following:

```
ID3D11Buffer **buffers;    //ID3D11Buffer is a com object
buffers=new ID3D11Buffer* [num];
```

Then if I do this:

```
delete[] buffers;
```

Will the `Release()` method of each `ID3D11Buffer*` be called automatically, or do I have to call them myself?

Comment: Start with 'std::vector<CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> > buffers;' then all your life-time management issues will disappear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All `delete[] buffers;` will do is free the array containing the pointers to the COM objects. You do need to loop through the array and `Release()` each of them by hand.

Comment: Ok, so would Release be called if I did something like delete buffers[0]?

Comment: No sir. All that would do is prematurely free the memory belonging to the COM object. Like [Mark Ransom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) says below, because the pointers are just that-- dumb pointers, they won't automatically call `Release()` or do any other cleanup.

Answer (score 9):

Calling `delete` on an array will destroy each element of the array. But since each element is a POD dumb pointer, destructing it doesn't do anything.  If you want the COM objects to be released automatically, you should use a smart pointer such as [_com_ptr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [CComPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Agreed, but in my experience the `com_ptr_t` is superior in every aspect to the ATL smart pointers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28VS.80%29.aspx More lightweight, not ATL runtime dependency, exception throw semantics for errors.

Comment: +1, also `std::vector` is a suitable container for both `CComPtr` and `_com_ptr_t`.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu, I've never looked into the differences between the COM smart pointers, indeed I forgot there was more than one. I'll defer to your opinion and update my answer.